# How to create PDF file with only one long page?

Tags: android, pdf, kotlin

I have a very big `HTML` file. For now, i'm using `HTML2PDF` converter to make PDF from HTML, which works just fine for me, but it splited my html to a few pages. But what i want to achieve is the whole HTML content on one (long) single page. How can i do this (without $ libs) ?
Maybe i can `foreach` every single page in my `pdf` document and "merge" it in a one big page ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I guess you need to give big enough page height parameter somehow for Html2Pdf.